# handle the order of soap messages in which they are sent

Tags: java, soap

I have web application in java where a client that listens for event from server another application in C++. There is a soap communication between client and server.At client side state machine is implemented to handle the states of client.

Now server can send as many events to client. Now, my problem is how will the client recognize the order of events. There is a possibility that event sent by server later arrives at client side earlier. Then how can I identify the order of events?

One solution is sequencing of events. But if second event is arrived first then should I ignore the second event and wait for the first and server resend the second event. Please provide the valuable suggestions on how to handle the order of soap messages?

Answer (score 0):

Soap Messages are synchronous by default, if you haven't specifically said that you are making a async webservice.

So, you don't need to bother about order of soap messages, the client gonna wait for a response from server untill it gets a response or timesout.

Its almost similar to our Browsers hiting the server, if you hit www.google.com with 3 different browsers, then what happens.